# Does a field weighs something?

Tags: electromagnetism, weight, levitation

Imagine you put a magnet on a scale and you could manage to keep another magnet with the same pole above it. So the upper magnet is floating above the other one with a magnetic field in between. Does the scale gives another weight compared with the situation that the magnets face each other with opposite poles?

Answer (score 3):

If the floating magnet is only supported by the repulsive magnetic force of the magnet on the scale, the scale shows the sum of the weight of both magnets. Therefore the weight measured is the same for the attractive or repulsive magnetic force.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, when the opposite poles face each other, the magnets will attract and join. The weight could be immeasurably different due to the lower potential. Does not mean though that the field has the weight of its own.